How to ensure that click on small button in tableview cell is recognized correctly?
I have a button on tableview cell in my UIKit App and when I tap on it, sometimes is recognized as a button click, and sometimes as a selection of the cell, itself.

So, what I can do to make that button work?

Generally, you want to make sure that the hit area is at least 44×44pt. See HIG - Buttons. So, make the buttons bigger/taller, and then center your graphical element inside that bigger button.

Make the whole image the tap target either by placing it in the button or use a tap gesture recogniser.
